# ETA for Selection Mark recognition?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

Is there a ETA for the selection mark recognition?
Maybe a preview we can join?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently no ETA yet. For Important Azure product updates, roadmap, and announcements. Subscribe to notifications to stay informed.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/?product=cognitive-services